# How to add a class if div height reaches a fixed height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some modules on my project that are generated dynamically. This basic HTML will work fine as an example of what I want to achieve:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image">  
        image here
    </div>
    <div class=" ellipsis">                            
        <div class="description">
            here we have a text not very long for a small module
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="end">
        buttom
    </div>                                              
</div>
```

My problem is that I don't want this module to ever grow too much vertically, if the web administrator writes a long "description" (I can't limit how much he wants to write as the "description" text will show on other pages).

I found a nice CSS trick to add "ellipsis" to a multiple lines container. Here you can see this "trick" in the `.ellipsis` (plus the basic CSS):

```
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    width:100px;
    margin:20px;
    float:left;    
}
.image {
    border:2px solid #999;
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.end {
    border:2px solid #999;
    width:100px;    
    background-color: #fff;
}

.ellipsis {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 200px;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    position:relative;
}

.ellipsis:before {
    content:"";
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    width: 5px; 
    height: 200px; 
}

.ellipsis > *:first-child {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px; 
}       

.ellipsis:after {
    content: "\02026";
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    float: right; position: relative;
    top: -25px; left: 100%; 
    width: 20px; margin-left: -20px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color:#eee; 
}
```

You can see everything together here: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/026at411/)

The problem I have is that while ellipsis works fine, I don't want ALL the modules to have a fixed height. I just want to limit the max-height to a fixed size. (Just delete "height: 200px;" from ".ellipsis:before" to see what I want to achieve.)

So, the problem is the `.ellipsis:before` fixed height. 100% height won't work unless I turn the position to absolute, but then the "ellipsis" trick won't work as the float won't take effect.

Any help with my problem will be greatly appreciated. I don't think there may be a pure CSS solution, (trust me, I have tried) and I'm very bad a JavaScript/jQuery. However, if you have a jQuery solution that may help, I could implement it in the project (and give you nice rep points here :) ). I was thinking something like:

If div.ellipsis > 200px then add height:200px to ellipsis:before

Thanks a lot in advance and please excuse my poor English. Hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Thank You for the "edit", Mr-Green. I apreciate it.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/026at411/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need of `:before` pseudo class. Check this fiddle.

```
.ellipsis:after {
    content:"\02026";
    position: absolute;   /* removed position: relative */
    top: 200px;           /* equal to max-height value */
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: -25px;    /* equal to line-height value */
    /* other styles */    /* removed float property */
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/026at411/8/)**

In the above fiddle, I removed `:before` pseudo class and set the position of the `:after` pseudo class to top by `200px` which is equal to the given `max-height` value of the `.ellipsis`.

and to remove the default upper and lower gaps of the container, I added `margin-top: -25px` which is equal to the given `line-height`.

Note: You can apply just `top: 175px` which is result value of subtraction of given `max-height` and `line-height` values.

Comment: That's the answer I can better implement. I apreciate it a lot. So simple yet so much time wasted trying to do this :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple jQuery solution.

First add a class for when an `ellipsis` reaches the maximum height, let's call it `maxed`. Set the `:before` height for that to `200px`:

```
.ellipsis.maxed:before {
    height:200px;
}
```

Then as you say. you can do some simple jQuery to check the height. If it is the maximum, then add our `maxed` class to the `ellipsis`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.container .ellipsis').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.height() >= 200) {
            $this.addClass('maxed');
        }
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/026at411/3/)

Comment: thanks a lot. Correct answer but I just can give credit to one correct answer. apreciate it though and I will keep the code for the future ( I definately need to learn jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with jquery (I assume jquery is an available option in your project).

You just have to

1. Remove all "ellipsis" class from HTML
2. Add "ellipsis" whenever needed with JS (= when your content exceeds 200px).

For that, you can use the following :

```
    $('.description').each(function(){
        if($(this).height() >= 200 ){
            $(this).parent().addClass('ellipsis');
        }
    });
```

[Working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/026at411/5/)

Comment: AS I comment on another mate answer, Nice (and correct) answer. Can give credit just to one though. Apreciate it anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly manipulate pseudo elements like :before. What you could do here is add a class for large ellipsis with `height: 200px`. Then use jQuery to add the new class according to the height.

```
$(function() {
  $('div.ellipsis').each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).height() >= 200) {
      $(element).addClass('ellipsis-large');
    }
  });
});
```

See the code snippet for the full example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div.ellipsis').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).height() >= 200) {
      $(element).addClass('ellipsis-large');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.image {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.end {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* ellipsis class for small modules */

.ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 200px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.ellipsis:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  /*   height: 200px; */
}
.ellipsis > *:first-child {
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.ellipsis:after {
  content: "\02026";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #eee;
}
/* ellipsis class for large modules */

.ellipsis-large:before {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    image here
  </div>
  <div class=" ellipsis">
    <div class="description">
      here we have a text not very long for a small module
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="end">
    buttom
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    image here
  </div>
  <div class=" ellipsis">
    <div class="description">
      here we have a text not very long for a small module
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="end">
    buttom
  </div>

</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    image here
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    <div class="description">and here we have a much longer text to reach the 200px "ellipsis" div to activate the effect made with pure css. a nice discovery from http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="end">
    buttom
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is valid, but means duplicating an awful lot of CSS

Comment: Yeah, I changed that. I saw the other answers while creating mine and posted mine just to promote the use of the code snippet since yours already has a working solution.

Comment: Thanks for your time Raidri. Another valid answer even if too much css